# Валидация input type="file" при помощи JQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery

Для валидации формы использую [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), работает для всех полей, кроме поля `<input type="file" id="ProjectInformation">`. Для которого я проверяю допустимость расширений загруженного файла

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#feedback-form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        },
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            ProjectInformation: {
                extension: "doc|txt|pdf",
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Name: {
                required: "Please enter a name",
                minlength: "Name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            ProjectInformation: {
                extension: "Only .doc, .txt, and .pdf files allowed",
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Получаю ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

В плагине **jquery.validate.js:572**

[image]

Если пытаюсь отправить пустую форму, и эту же ошибку в нескольких местах gkfubyf, если загружаю в `<input type=“file”>` какой-нибудь файл.